# jquery listeners not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my jquery animations and nothing i've tried has worked in terms of fixing the problem.

If you go here you'll see the issue:

http://mikeheavers.com/clients/niko/

- when you roll over one of the thumbnails, it will sometimes hide and show itself in rapid succession. If I try to make sure it is not animated before animating, then sometimes the titles just stick and never animate out. Same thing with using a callback. Here's my current code:

HTML:

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="temp/thumb.jpg" alt="Thumb"/>
    <div class="thumb_overlay">
        <p>Hunter Douglas</p>
    </div>
    <img class="thumb_plus" alt="View Larger Image" src="images/site/icon_plus.png"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $('.thumb').mouseover(function(){

        if ($chosenThumb != null){
            $lastThumb = $chosenThumb;
        }

        $chosenThumb = $(this);

        console.log($lastThumb + "|" + $chosenThumb + "|" + ($lastThumb == $chosenThumb)); //THIS NEVER EVALUATES AS TRUE - WHAT'S UP WITH THAT?

        if ($lastThumb != $chosenThumb && $lastThumb != null){
            $lastThumb.children('.thumb_overlay').animate({ 'height' : '0px'}, 200);
            $lastThumb.children('.thumb_plus').animate({'height' :'0px', 'width' : '0px' },200);
        }

    if ($chosenThumb != $lastThumb){
        $chosenThumb.children('.thumb_overlay').animate({ 'height' : '30px'}, 200);
        $chosenThumb.children('.thumb_plus').animate({'height' :'31px', 'width' : '31px' },200);
    }
});
```

What do I need to do to get this working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your mouseover event is on the container.  When an element moves over the element you're mousing over it blocks the mouse from the element with the mouseover event triggering a mouseout event.

The solution is to create an element that transparently blocks the whole thumb that can intercept the event without triggering a mouseout.

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="temp/thumb.jpg" alt="Thumb"/>
    <div class="thumb_overlay">
        <p>Hunter Douglas</p>
    </div>
    <img class="thumb_plus" alt="View Larger Image" src="images/site/icon_plus.png"/>
    <div class="block_thumb"></div>
</div>
```

If you put your events on .block_thumb and you make block_thumb have absolute positioning and height and width equal to the .thumb height and width you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `stop()` in before your animation. Example:

`$lastThumb.children('.thumb_overlay').stop().animate({ 'height' : '0px'}, 200);`

Answer (score 1):

You must stop the current animation before starting another on the same object because they are queued..

change your `if`s to

```
if ($lastThumb != $chosenThumb && $lastThumb != null){
    $lastThumb.children('.thumb_overlay').stop().animate({ 'height' : '0px'}, 200);
    $lastThumb.children('.thumb_plus').stop().animate({'height' :'0px', 'width' : '0px' },200);
}

if ($chosenThumb != $lastThumb){
    $chosenThumb.children('.thumb_overlay').stop().animate({ 'height' : '30px'}, 200);
    $chosenThumb.children('.thumb_plus').stop().animate({'height' :'31px', 'width' : '31px' },200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is that the mouseover is firing multiple times, then add a conditional in there to make sure it doesn't happen

for example, try this code instead (see the "is-animating" lines):

```
$('.thumb').mouseover(function(){

        // is this already animating?
        var $this=$(this);
        if ($this.data('is-animating')) {
            return;
        }

        if ($chosenThumb != null){
            $lastThumb = $chosenThumb;
        }

        $chosenThumb = $this;

        // mark this so future events know it's already animating
        $this.data('is-animating', true);

        console.log($lastThumb + "|" + $chosenThumb + "|" + ($lastThumb == $chosenThumb)); //THIS NEVER EVALUATES AS TRUE - WHAT'S UP WITH THAT?

        if ($lastThumb != $chosenThumb && $lastThumb != null){
            $lastThumb.children('.thumb_overlay').animate({ 'height' : '0px'}, 200);
            $lastThumb.children('.thumb_plus').animate({'height' :'0px', 'width' : '0px' },200);
        }

    if ($chosenThumb != $lastThumb){
        $chosenThumb.children('.thumb_overlay').animate({ 'height' : '30px'}, 200);
        $chosenThumb.children('.thumb_plus').animate({'height' :'31px', 'width' : '31px' },200);
    }

    // unmark it after the animation's finished
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.data('is-animating', false);
    }, 200);

});
```